# PowerShell -Replace appending (oddly) instead of replacing

Tags: powershell

**EDIT:** PowerShell version is 5.1

I am writing some code that will take the value of a variable from a file, and if that string is made up of other variables within the file, it will locate them and replace it to reconstruct the run-time value. It assumes the variable contains a string, and that the string describes a directory.

For example, the file contains:

```bsh
$var0 = "C:\Users\v-anad\Documents"
$var1 = "$var0\TestFolder"
```

Then when the code looks for `$var1`, it should return something like: `"C:\Users\v-anad\Documents\TestFolder\"`

However, the actual output I see is:
`\TestFolder"-anad\Documents"`

When it replaces, it deletes the correct substring (`$var0`), but when it inserts the value of `$var0`, it skips over the characters that existed there before, and appends the remaining characters to the end of the string. I have no clue what/where I've gone wrong.

Here is the code in question:

```bsh
function Get-Var-Value-In-File([string]$varName, [string]$file) {
    $regex = "(?<=\$varName = )[^`n]*"
    $content = Get-Content -Raw $file
    return  [regex]::Match($content, $regex).Value
}

$file = 'C:\Users\v-anad\Documents\TestFolder\TestVars.ps1'
$var = '$var1'
$value = Get-Var-Value-In-File $var $file
$regex = "\$[^\\]*"
$nextVar = [regex]::Match($value, $regex).Value
$nextValue = Get-Var-Value-In-File $nextVar $file

Write-Output "$var = $value"
Write-Output "$nextVar = $nextValue"
Write-Output $nextVar.Replace($nextVar, $nextValue)
Write-Output ($value -replace [regex]::Escape($nextVar),$nextValue)
```

Output:

```bsh
$var1 = "$var0\TestFolder"
$var0 = "C:\Users\v-anad\Documents"
"C:\Users\v-anad\Documents"
\TestFolder"-anad\Documents"
```

Note how the code above does not account for the extra quotes that would be inserted into the final value, so should this curious behavior be fixed, the output will be: `""C:\Users\v-anad\Documents"\TestFolder\"`

Comment: Are you using regex to parse powershell files?  Do you know about Abstract Syntax Trees (ASTs)?

Comment: [I can not reproduce your behavior.](https://tio.run/##fVBdS4RAFH2fXzGIoIZK@yotLVQbPVQQ1T44Lg3u3V3BHWVm3Bai327XUdOkGhDGM@fr3rJ4B6n2kOd1va1EqrNC0FvQwSuX@OUVBHciWGY5uLHSMhO7xD5y@cAP4NNvZIvvHv0gFI8tYQcnOqeWe3kxZz0bAS9ev4nkzGppaSE0CI34wiEN67zRXEXsRWEjdgy44Bt2XaTVAWnKMpxZwzFk9gxKL4t8A9IizsJ4StCVFJTGpkISRfdcp3u3j/K7bl5oBiOfhJjm6On8mTvKMVfciwpLNWs7N1LTy/yiKQK/bo8atokjw4aYHa8Za1ZiCzg13ohO2xvfafeO/29ib9mmkpXMNASPlS4r3S4Rpa27NX0c2gxBE1LPCZ@gzHkKbg/4I433U9MNQwPZaoZZb1TKy8HD80cedf0F) Can you provide more information about your environment, like PowerShell version, etc.

Comment: @PetSerAl `$PSVersionTable.PSVersion` reports 5.1

Comment: Also it's the desktop edition, I'm not running PowerShell Core like in your TIO link

Comment: This looks like an [X-Y problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) to me. Please take a step back and describe the actual problem you're trying to solve instead of what you perceive as the solution. What do you need this "parse and expand variables" for?

Comment: I see your issue now: you have ``Write-Output "`"`"C:\Users\v-anad\Documents`"`r\TestFolder`""`` instead of ``Write-Output "`"`"C:\Users\v-anad\Documents`"\TestFolder`""``.

Comment: @PetSerAl Yep! That solved it, thanks. Forgot about carriage returns. Would you mind posting an answer so I could mark it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was there was a carriage return (\r, or `r in PowerShell) that my regex included in the match, causing the behavior when the string replacement occurred. Thanks to [PerSerAl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4003407/petseral) for being a second pair of eyes to catch it.